# Should canvas fill() method be called before or after closing the path()?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am unable to understand the behavior of the HTML Canvas [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill) method. By definition, it should fill current path or given path. However, I notice that `fill` method's behavior is same irrespective of where I put it i.e. before or after closing my path using [`closePath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath) method. It still ends up filling my square drawn using Canvas `path` exactly same way.

```js
function draw(context) {
  context.fillStyle = "#FF1010";

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0, 0);
  context.lineTo(100, 0);
  context.lineTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(0, 100);
  context.lineTo(0, 0);
  context.closePath();
  
  // Where should this be?
  context.fill();
}
```

So, what's the correct way to use the `fill` method.

Comment: Fill will close the last open path, in the set of current paths, for you. Using `closePath` as done in the snippet provide is not needed. BTW neither is the last `.lineTo(0, 0);` in your example, And, the first `moveTo` after `beginPath` can also be a `lineTo`

Comment: @Blindman67, So if `fill` closes the last open path and if, I have, for example, five distinct paths and then I call `fill()` method after closing all those five paths, is it going to fill only last closed path? What will happen to remaining four?

Comment: In regards to `fill` each `moveTo` will close the previous open path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `closePath()` for filling the path, it's done automatically.
Enclosed subpaths* do matter for stroking, for instance a closed rect won't render the same stroke as an unclosed quad of `lineTo`:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D();
path.moveTo(20, 20);
path.lineTo(70, 20);
path.lineTo(70, 70);
path.lineTo(20, 70);
path.lineTo(20, 20);

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke(path);
// closed path on the right
ctx.translate(80, 0);
path.closePath();
ctx.stroke(path);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

But `fill` will treat both exactly the same:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const path = new Path2D();
path.moveTo(20, 20);
path.lineTo(70, 20);
path.lineTo(70, 70);
path.lineTo(20, 70);
// only 3 lineto on the left
ctx.fill(path);
// 4 lineto in the center
ctx.translate(80, 0);
path.lineTo(20, 20);
ctx.fill(path); 
// closed path on the right
ctx.translate(80, 0);
path.closePath();
ctx.fill(path);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Also, to clear things up, since it seems that even answerers here are still confused, `closePath()` doesn't mean that your path declaration is over. It just means that the previous "sub-path" is enclosed; to make things easier than are, it's just a `lineTo` to the last `moveTo` point. If you keep adding path commands after that it will stil use that sub-path and will also start from that point.

To start a new path declaration you call `ctx.beginPath()`.

.* a new subpath is created at each call to `moveTo`, `closePath`, `rect` and `roundRect`.

Answer (score 0):

From a logical point of view the correct way would be to close the path before calling `fill()` simply because without a closed path, there won't be anything to fill. For convenience though your path gets closed automatically as soon as you call fill().

Remember though, that if you don't close the path at all and use additional drawing operations afterwards it will continue using the previous path.