# Canvas not showing some paths

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why are my paths sometimes not showing up when calculated by my internal functions from variables like `%`?

When developing simple graphic tool to create fillable templates which I can convert to images, I noticed that sometimes my drawn paths were disappearing depending on their positioning. This could be fixed by adding `0.02px` or `Number.ESPSILON` to some points, but this is not really a solution. Why is that happening?

Code in question:

```js
  // Starts with setting canvas
  async setCanvas() {
    this.$self.get.loading.style.display = '';
    this.canvas = this.$self.get.canvas;
    this.canvas.setAttribute('width', this.canvas.offsetWidth * this.$.scale)
    this.canvas.setAttribute('height', this.canvas.offsetHeight * this.$.scale)
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.picture.x = this.decimal(((this.canvas.offsetWidth - this.$.width) / 2)*this.$.scale);
    this.picture.y = this.decimal(((this.canvas.offsetHeight - this.$.height) / 2)*this.$.scale);
    this.drawCanvas();
    // Then we draw on it
    await this.draw();
    this.loaderDebouncer();
  }

  [...]

  async draw() {
    for(let i=0; i < this.$.layout.length; i++) {
      const layout = this.$.layout[i];
      Object.values(layout.inputs || {}).forEach(input => {
        // this should not be relevant as is just integration of Form framework
        if (!input.object) {
          input.object = FormBuilder.sGenerateFieldItem(input.value || null);
          this.setMain(input.value, layout, input);
        }
      });
      await this.drawEntity(layout);
    }
  }
  
 [...]

 async drawEntity(entity) {
    const types = {
      image: e => this.drawImage(e),
      rect: e => this.drawRect(e),
      text: e => this.drawText(e),
      polygon: e => this.drawPolygon(e), // <- draws the path
      default: e => console.error('Not recognized type', e.type),
    };

    await (types[entity.type] || types.default)(entity);
  }

  // !! The relevant method!
  async drawPolygon(entity) {
    const data = entity.data,
      path = await this.retrieveValue(data.path || [], entity),  
      { width, height, left, top } = this.calculateSizeAndPos(entity),
      x = this.decimal(this.picture.x + left),
      y = this.decimal(this.picture.y + top);

    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);

    path.forEach(point => {
      this.polygonFunction(x, y, point[0])(...point.slice(1));
    });

    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.fill(data.fill) || this.ctx.fillStyle;
    this.ctx.fill();
    this.ctx.closePath();

    if (entity.custom) {
      entity.custom(this.ctx);
    }

    if (entity.outline) {
      const outline = entity.outline;
      this.polygonFunction(x, y, 'stroke')(this.thickness(outline.thickness || 5), this.fill(outline.fill || '#000'));
    }

    this.ctx.restore();
  }

  polygonFunction(x, y, type) {
    const fns = {
      line: (lineX, lineY,) => {
        lineX = this.decimal(x + this.calc(lineX, 'x')), lineY = this.decimal(y + this.calc(lineY, 'y'));
        this.ctx.lineTo(lineX, lineY)
      },
      curve: (cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, curveX, curveY) => {
        cp1x = this.decimal(x + this.calc(cp1x, 'x'));
        cp1y = this.decimal(y + this.calc(cp1y, 'y'));
        cp2x = this.decimal(x + this.calc(cp2x, 'x'));
        cp2y = this.decimal(y + this.calc(cp2y, 'y'));
        curveX = this.decimal(x + this.calc(curveX, 'x'));
        curveY = this.decimal(y + this.calc(curveY, 'y'));

        this.ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, curveX, curveY);
      },
      stroke: (thickness, fill) => {
        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = fill || '#000';
        this.ctx.lineWidth =  this.thickness(thickness, 5);
        this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        this.ctx.miterLimit = 2;
        this.ctx.stroke();
        this.ctx.restore();
      },
      default: () => fns.line(...arguments),
    };

    return fns[type] || fns.default
  }

  decimal(number, precision = 2) {
    return +number.toFixed(precision);
  }

  retrieveValue(value, entity) {
    if (typeof value == 'function') {
      return value(entity, this.$.indexes, this);
    }

    return value;
  }

  calculateSizeAndPos(entity) {
    return {
      width: this.calc(entity.size?.w, 'x'),
      height: this.calc(entity.size?.h, 'y'),
      left: this.calc(entity.pos?.x, 'x'),
      top: this.calc(entity.pos?.y, 'y')
    }
  }
```

Settings used for the disappearing path:

```js
      {
        id: 'arrow',
        label: 'Rune Position',
        editable: true,
        type: 'polygon',
        pos: {
          x: '42.5%',
          y: '60%',
        },
        data: {
          path: layer => {
            if (layer.inputs.position.value == 0) {
              layer.data.fill = '#FFF';
              layer.outline.fill = '#000';

              return [
                ['line', '1.5%', '2.5w%'],
                ['line', '-1.5%', '2.5w%'],
              ];
            }

            layer.data.fill = '#000';
            layer.outline.fill = '#FFF';

            return [
              ['line', '1.5%', '0'],
              ['line', '0', '2.5w%'],
              ['line', '-1.5%', '0'],
            ];
          },
          fill: '#FFF'
        },
        outline: {
          fill: '#000',
          thickness: .5,
        },
        inputs: {
          position: {
            type: 'select',
            label: 'Rune Position',
            options: [
              ['Top', '0'],
              ['Bottom', '1'],
            ],
            value: '0',
            inherited: null,
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that causes the bug in your question? Otherwise it's impossible for us to see what's going wrong.

Comment: That's cool, but with only the above code, it's still not easy to reproduce your error. Your code seems to be part of a class? You are loading JSON? Have you tried just hardcoding your path and drawing it, to see what happens?

Comment: I didn't include my code in the first place because it uses parts of the bigger framework, so it is impossible to include it all. This is all the code of the class minus some utils like css class provider etc. I did try to write it by hand and passing just values, but it resulted in the same problem.

Comment: Can't you reduce it to some hardcoded calls to `ctx.lineTo(x, y); ctx.lineTo(x1, y1); ctx.lineTo(x', y');` which does expose said behavior? That's what **we** need to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this one. It looks like a bug on Firefox 114.0.1 (64-bit) Linux (Ubuntu 20) as opening the page in incognito tag or another browser (Chrome) fixes it for that session.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason closing the path before filling it made it disappear (?). Changing the order of the functions removed this problem on all instances.
From:

```js
this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
[...draw]
this.ctx.closePath();
this.ctx.fill();
this.ctx.stroke();
```

To:

```js
this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
[...draw]
this.ctx.fill();
this.ctx.closePath();
this.ctx.stroke();
```

Regarding appearance of the paths they should stay the same as there is no visible difference for filling the paths without calling `closePath` first (check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72567642/11495586).

Comment: -1 Sorry but your conclusion is wrong and as such the answer is very bad advice. There is no need to round values presented to the 2D API. FYI JS `Number `is a double (64bit floating point)) 2D API uses `float` (32bit floating point) converting from double to float still results in a rounding errors (thats how floating point works).  eg `(new Float32Array([(0.2 + 0.1).toFixed(2)]))[0] == 0.30000001192092896`. The rounding may have fixed your problem, but your bug is still there!

Comment: Oh damn, okay thanks for that! I will look some more and try to update the answer